# Reading data from DB using Entity Framework results in missing fields of an object

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I currently have 2 models. One model references the other model. I am able to write the data perfectly well to the db. however when I read the data I get an incomplete object. One of the fields of that object is missing. This is what my models look like

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public List<Sport> Sports { get; set; }

    public string StudentName { get; set; }
}

public class Sport
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string SportName { get; set; }
}

public class DbContext : DbContext
{

    public DbContext()
        : base("name=StudentContext")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

Now I am writing the Student object like this

```
//Writing to the DB
Student stud = new Student()
{
    StudentName = "Andrew",
};

stud.Sports = sportList; //Contains a sport List
this.context.Students.Add(device);
this.context.SaveChanges();
```

After writing the object to the DB I noticed that both the tables got populated and it looks good. However when I attempt to read the object back like this
The Sport List in Student does not get populated and comes back as NULL

```
 //Reading from DB - Sports field missing
 var a = this.context.Students.FirstOrDefault();
 List<Sport> actions = a.Sports; //Returns null Why ??
```

Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong ? How can I get the sports field as well ?

Comment: Try changing it to: `var a = this.context.Students.Include(x => x.Sports).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: When doing a SELECT, Entity Framework won't include mapped entities unless you tell... ah, I see Matt.G beat me to it.

Comment: Yep that did the job. @Matt.G can you put that down as the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**change in edmx file**

```
<EntityContainer Name="StudentContext" annotation:LazyLoadingEnabled="false">
```

**OR**

```
{

    public DbContext()
        : base("name=StudentContext")
    {
         this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
         this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }

    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

**Or you can also modify your query**

```
var a = this.context.Students.Include(s => s.Sports).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Isnt `this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true`  should be false

Comment: I tried with the second example and I still get back a null.

Comment: Event with `this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;` I get back a null.

Comment: change ProxyCreationEnabled status aslo

Comment: can you explain how we can change the ProxyCreationEnabled status ?

Comment: LazyLoading does not work when ProxyCreationEnabled == false. This is because lazy loading works by adding additional code into your model classes to support lazy loading.

Comment: What is your EF version

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199205/discussion-between-moinul-islam-and-mistyd).

Answer (score 1):

Actually you do NOT need to do this (and you should not because in this way all the navigation properties inside the current `DbContext` will be eager loaded):

```
this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

According to the reference you have already disabled lazy loading for the navigation property `Sports` by declaring it as a non-virtual property.

> Loading of the `Sports` collection can still be achieved using [eager loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data#eagerly-loading) or the [`Load`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data#explicitly-loading) method.

(Adapted to this case from the doc)